# How to run test go file in a go package?

Tags: go

There are files like `read_test.go` in `https://github.com/google/codesearch`. How to run this kind of test go file? Thanks.

Comment: The document  https://golang.org/doc/code.html answers some of your questions.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: `go test` and read the documentation for it with `go help test`. Probably you should read what `go help` tells you too.

Answer (score 0):

In the main directory:

```
go test ./...
```

For more information:

```
go help test
```

and [testing package](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

Comment: But I removed `go.mod`. For reason mentioned in a comment here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238989/how-to-build-go-package-locally/62239279. How to run the test in this case?

Comment: Is the project in your GOPATH?

Comment: If the project is out of the correct dir in GOPATH, you need `go.mod`. You can follow these steps so you don't need `go.mod` : 
`cd ~`
`mkdir go`
`export GOPATH=~/go`
`go get github.com/google/codesearch`
`cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/google/codesearch`
`rm go.mod`
`go test ./...`

Comment: The code is just cloned in a regular directory. But it is not in GOPATH, nor installed in GOPATH.

Comment: OK, without GOPATH you cannot delete the `go.mod` file. If you follow the instructions above you can run or test the project. You can choose any directory for GOPATH, just replace `go` dir with your desired directory in the above instructions

Comment: Create the go.mod again. Why did you even delete it in the first place? If you're using standard packages, then you can kinda' ignore it, but if there are external packages used then why would you delete the go.mod (Go modules makes life much easier).